# Representing a tree where the root has exactly one child of this specific type

Tags: inheritance, tree, constraints, uml, class-diagram

I want to model a tree, which a situation where a class `Node` is composed of multiple instances of itself.

Now how to indicates a constraint like "The root of the tree may contains as many node as needed, but shall only have one instance of this specific type of node" (the special node itself may contain anything

With a diagram a indicated below, we have a conflict between the two composition, I shall be able to add as many `specialElement` as a want to a root, because they are `treeNodes`.

How could I represent this constraint?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current model has a flaw: `root` and `specialElement` both inherit the composition with `TreeNode` that they soecialize. The composition that you represent between `root` and `specialElement` is therefore understood an additional one.

There are three easy ways out:

- use [Jim’s excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67640631/3723423) base on subsetting. But this requires to document explicitly the roles at each end of the composition.
- show visually that the composition between `root` and `specialElement` is a specialization of the reflexive composition of `TreeNode` (just add the [generalization arrow on the diagram between the lines representing composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66724007/3723423)).
- remove the additional redundant composition and instead add a [constraint](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/how-to-model-constraints-in-uml/) in a note attached to `root` for example in plaintext `{ can have at most one specialElement child node }`  (but I’m sure someone will manage to express this formally in OCL ;-) )

For more ideas, you may also look at [this question about covariant associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973692/how-to-model-a-covariant-association-class-in-uml) in UML.

Comment: Thanks, I also used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034010/how-to-use-subsetted-property-in-uml to understand subsetting

Answer (score 1):

You are missing properties at the ends of your associations. A more specific property can subset a more general property and have a multiplicity of exactly [1].

Comment: I guess you'd need to supply a drawing to make it a good answer. Especially ths `subsets` part is not obvious.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and I’ll upvote if you add a diagram !